# Any build instructions for vertical Technic/Lego conveyor belts?

Tags: technic, mindstorms, motor, gbc

I'm trying to figure out how to continuously lift a stream of incoming pieces up vertically, at least 10cm. This is my first real custom build attempt, so I'm very much at a loss on how to go about it. Are there books or sites or other resource likely to contain part lists and build instructions for a vertical conveyor belt?

Only thing I've found so far is this absolutely **delightful** video of The Great Ball Contraption, but while providing lots of inspiration, I don't know enough to reverse engineer it or even really figure out which parts are which.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=jxMMtIxDrGk

I'm starting from scratch on parts, aside from the Educational Mindstorms EV3 base set.

Comment: By the way it's not **The** Great Ball Contraption. As far as I know, they set up another one at every fair! With different parts depending on who decided to bring one to the fair. Each person makes one section, and they join them all together.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're in luck! Jason at [JK BrickWorks](https://jkbrickworks.com/marble-run-elevator-and-alternator/) has put his instructions online. There are others I've used; I'll hunt for those links, too. He's made multiple Ideas sets, so this might be how Lego officially makes a marble run set, which would be **fantastic**.

Here we go: I've built [Brian Alano's wheel lift](https://lawriege.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/Wheel-Lift-12x12-1.pdf?3e5ecc&3e5ecc) and [Bryan Bonahoom's stackable lift](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5d53ea2208034a00012c0a1e/t/5e42b80bca0f7862fc7cea45/1581430799032/Stackable+GBC%2C+rev+11.pdf) and enjoyed great success with both.

On EuroBricks, there has been a lot of work posted on [recreating Akiyuki's modules](https://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/117305-gbc-the-akiyuki-project-2010-2020/).

Comment: That’s a stunning wealth of useful information! Thanks so much!